# How to deallocate array of pointers to structures in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I've created class that implements array of pointers to structures... I know how to add records to this array, but I don't know, how to delete them properly and thus I've got memory leaks. The size of my array rises when needed and I know the size of an array and how many records do I have there. I'm used to code in languages, that have garbage collector, so this is quite confusing for me. I'd be glad if any of you could show me, how to deallocate properly that array.

Pls note, that I can't use `vector`. I'm limited on includes to those:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
```

My code :

```
struct DbRecord
{
    string oName;
    string oAddr;
    string cName;
    string cAddr;
};

class CCompanyIndex
{
    public: CCompanyIndex(void);~CCompanyIndex(void);
    bool Add(const string & oName,
    const string & oAddr,
    const string & cName,
    const string & cAddr);
    bool Del(const string & oName,
    const string & oAddr);
    bool Search(const string & oName,
    const string & oAddr,
    string & cName,
    string & cAddr) const;

    int size;
    int position;
    DbRecord * * db;
};

CCompanyIndex::CCompanyIndex(void)
{
    db = new DbRecord * [1000];

    size = 1000;
    position = 0;
}

CCompanyIndex::~CCompanyIndex(void)
{
}

int main(int argc, char const * argv[])
{

    CCompanyIndex c1;
    // do something..with c1, i.e. add there some records to array
    // ...
    // ...
    // delete it now
}
```

Comment: How you need to delete depends on how you add (e.g. whether you add contiguously, etc). Could you show us that code?

Comment: Also, since you're using C++, why not use a vector instead of an array? It will make it much easier to add and remove elements. You could use a vector of pointers, e.g. `vector<DbRecord*> db`

Comment: @maditya I can't use vector, because it's a homework and we've got limited includes.. I add records the way, I've got them on indexes from `0` to `position` . If I delete some, I just decrease `position` value, so next record will be added on the rigt place. So the size of an array might be 0-10000 but records will be allways on `0` - `position`, thus value of `position` <= value of `size`

Comment: There are two errors in his code: using array new rather than `std::vector`, and using pointers to a value type.

Comment: @maditya If you can't use `std::vector` for this, then there is _no_ correct C++ solution.  Any professor who suggests using array new should be fired, because he is manifestly incompetent.

Comment: @Dworza are you not allowed to use std::vector?

Comment: @JamesKanze Agreed ...

Comment: Nope...this should be homework for practicing dynamically allocated arrays and pointers... I'd also love to use `vector` but I can't ~_~

Comment: That's unfortunate. Ok ... what makes you think there is a memory leak in the program?

Comment: We've got system to check our homeworks and it says, that I don't free allocated memory. I tried to call delete db[]; in my destructor, nevertheless that doesn't unallocate pointers to structures..

Comment: You have to individually delete all the pointers in your array of pointers, before your delete your array of pointers. So you need to iterate through the array, delete every pointer that is valid (up to position), and then `delete  db[]`

Comment: Also, I notice you have a `Search` function, so you may not be removing data in the reverse order that you were adding it ... so you might be deleting from a pointer that is in the middle of your array, which means it is no longer contiguous. Decreasing the size of position will cause a memory leak if the element you are deleting is not the last one ...

Comment: I can assure you, that it is contiguous. `Search` function is only implemented binary search and it only says, if there is such record in my array yet, so I didn't find out it necessary to post it here.. I'm really new to C++ so I've got problems with very simple things... How to call my destructor in `main` ? Just `delete c1;` ? Or it's being called automaticaly after the program ends?

Comment: No, you don't need to call `delete` on c1 since it is allocated on the stack. In C++, objects are allocated on the heap only if you use `new` or `malloc` (e.g. your data structs). These need to be memory managed. The destructor is automatically called for objects on the stack when they go out of scope (which is at the end of your program in the case of c1).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27274/discussion-between-maditya-and-dworza)

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::vector` to avoid having to manage memory manually through raw pointers, `new[]`, and `delete[]`. Doing so is (as you experienced) error-prone and easily leads to memory leaks or undefined behavior.

I also suggest using smart pointers instead of raw pointers for holding references to `DbRecord` objects, for the very same reason. You should choose your smart pointer according to the desired ownership policy. Here, I will assume `std::shared_ptr` is appropriate.

Notice, however, that if you do *not* need reference semantics, then you should not use pointers at all, and rather declare your container as `std::vector<DbRecord>` instead. Here I will assume that you do need reference semantics, since your original version used (raw) pointers; but again, if you do not, don't use pointers.

So given the necessary `#include` directives and `using` declarations:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::shared_ptr;
```

And the (unchanged) definition of your `DbRecord` data structure:

```
struct DbRecord {
    string oName;
    string oAddr;
    string cName;
    string cAddr;
};
```

You can change the definition of your `CCompanyIndex` this way (as you can see, the user-defined default constructor and destructor are now superfluous, and you can let the compiler generate them implicitly):

```
class CCompanyIndex {
public:

//  No more need for a user-defined default constructor and destructor!

    bool Add(const string & oName,
            const string & oAddr,
            const string & cName,
            const string & cAddr);
    bool Del(const string & oName,
            const string & oAddr);
    bool Search(const string & oName,
            const string & oAddr,
            string & cName,
            string & cAddr) const;

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<DbRecord>> db;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Finally, notice that you won't need to perform any manual cleanup:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    CCompanyIndex c1;
    // do something..with c1, i.e. add there some records to array
    // ...
    // ...

    // NO NEED TO MANUALLY DELETE IT NOW!
}
```

Comment: Any pointer (smart or other) to a class with value semantics is probably not the best solution.  Classes with value semantics can be copied; there's no reason to allocate them dynamically, and there's no reason to take their address.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well, you don't know whether the application needs reference semantics, and if he used pointers in the original version, there are reasons to believe it does. Of course, if that's not the case, `vector<DbRecord>` is preferable. But we can't tell that without seeing the rest

Comment: The class he shows us has value semantics.  And there's no more reason to suppose that he needs pointers to it than to suppose he needs array new to create his vector.  (Of course, if `DbRecord` were an entity class, then it shouldn't be owned by the vector, and raw pointers are fine.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: The fact that the data structure is not an entity class does not mean he does not need reference semantics. He might hold pointers to the same object, one in a collection and one outside of the collection, and require changes performed through one pointer to be visible when the data members are accessed through the other pointer (reference semantics). We can't tell if this is the case unless we see the rest of the code.

Comment: pls see my update to check, what includes can I use...Vector is not included :-/

Answer (score 1):

The rule of a thumb is to reverse in the destructor the operations done in the constructor related to memory management.
That said, since you have `db = new DbRecord * [1000];` in the constructor, you should have a `delete[] db;` in the destructor.

Note, however that most likely you do not need dynamic memory management here (use the by value semantics) and you may want to look into higher-level abstractions that C++ offers, such as `vector` class - like was suggested by AndyProwl and JamesKanze.

Comment: but if I use only `delete[] db;` then I don't free memory for the pointers to the structure... If it would only array of structures, your solution would work fine, but I've got array of pointers to strucutures..

Comment: @Dworza That's right. But in your code I don't see allocations beyond the one in the constructor. Of course, if you allocate more stuff, you should release it as well. In your case it would probably be iterating over the array and calling `delete` for each item.

Comment: and how to check if is `NULL` in C++ ? `db[i] == 0` ? and haw to call destructor in my `main` ? Just to write `delete c1;` ?

Comment: You can check as `(db[i] == 0)` but you don't need it if it's for deletion. Operator `delete` is designed to work with null pointers, you can safely call `delete db[i]` without checking for null.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing any memory management here.  There is
practically never any reason for using array new; just use
`std::vector`.  And there's really no reason for dynamically
allocating your `DbRecord`; since it has value semantics:

```
std::vector<DbRecord> db;
```

does the job nicely.

Comment: I can name a few reasons: performance, binary size, availability of standard library, std::array, exercise. Note, the OP has edited the question - he can't use `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use operators `delete` and `delete[]` to free memory. For example, you may free memory in destructor as follows:

```
CCompanyIndex::~CCompanyIndex(void)
{
  // delete objects pointed-to in a loop. 
  // !! the objects MUST have been allocated, or the pointers MUST be set to null. 
  // note that 'delete' is null-safe. 
  for(DbRecord* it=db; it<db+position; ++it)
  {
    delete *it; 
  }

  // delete the array of pointers
  delete[] db;
}
```

`delete` frees memory allocated for a single object (via `new`), whereas `delete[]` frees memory allocated for array of objects (via `new[]`, as in your case).

*BUT* don't re-invent the wheel - just use `std::vector<DbRecord*>`. It does memory management for you, and your code will be simpler and more readable. C++ provides powerful standard library, so that most programmers don't even need to use manual memory management.